# Convert object literal notation to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object-literal

I used a literal as a dictionary, but a third party binding tool only takes arrays.

This is one way, is there a better one?

```
var arr = [];
$.each(objectLiteral, function () { arr.push(this); });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong with your solution.

This is a shorter one:

```
var arr = $.map(objectLiteral, function (value) { return value; });
```

Answer (score 8):

Your method is fine, clear and readable.  To do it without jQuery, use the `for (..in..)` syntax:

```
var arr = [];
for (prop in objectLiteral) {
  arr.push(objectLiteral[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In vanilla JS...

If we want to convert an object literal

```
var obj = {
 species: 'canine',
 name: 'Charlie',
 age: 4
}
```

into an array of arrays

```
[['species', 'canine'], ['name', 'Charlie'], ['age', 4]]
```

here is one way

```
function objToArr(obj){
  var arr = [];

  for (var key in obj){
    arr.push([key, obj[key]]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const objectLiteral = { hell: 'devil' };

const ver1 = Object.keys(objectLiteral); // ['hell']
const ver2 = Object.values(objectLiteral); // ['devil']
const ver3 = Object.entries(objectLiteral); // [['hell', 'devil']]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 0):

In ES2017 you can now use `Object.entries` and with ES6 destructuring support you can use the resulting array pretty nice, example

```
Object.entries(objectLiteral).filter(([key, value]) => !!value).map(([key, value]) => key)
```

Gets you all properties with a value